# Git: Merge a branch but without some of the files I only need modified locally?

Tags: git, capistrano

I have this particular scenario, which is simple really, but I don't see (so far) a similar question here.

I'm working in my own branch copied from a remote repo, And I have added my own tasks to a **Capistrano Capfile**. These tasks will only help Me deploy the app to my own private server, Therefore when it's time to Merge my branch with *origin master*, I don't want the changes in the Capfile to be pushed to the **remote master repo**, because, obviously, this file should remain intact over there without my personal alterations.

What's the best practice to deal with this situation?

Thanks in advance!

PS. I guess that what I'm looking for, is a way to '**Git Ignore**' files exclusively for a branch. To over simplify things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to branch a now branch (lets name it `Local`) off from your current branch (lets name it `Original`).

In `Original`, you revert the changes you made to the capfile. In `Local`, you continue working on your data as usual. Before it comes to remerge into the remote, you merge `Local` to `Original` and just push `Original`. If you do not change the local Capfile further, it should be fine, otherwise you have to (again) revert those changes (although that should result in a merge conflict anyways, so you can handle it in the merge directly).

Comment: But, wouldn't the merge of Local to Original result in having the Same "modified" Capfile in both of the branches now? anyways, Your solution looks a little over-complex and I could easily get lost, Is there a way to git-ignore locally for just a branch? Thank you for your reply sir.

Comment: Of course you can git-ignore, but that will untrack the file complely. On the merge back you will not have the modified version in it, because the merge only applies diffs, not files. If you did not modify the capfile again in your branch, it will stay like it was before.

Comment: I had to put your solution to work, It may not be as straight-forward as I wished for, but, yes.. for now it does the trick, thanks!

Comment: This worked great for me. I've read a lot of answers to similar questions, and this seems like the simplest solution of all of them.

Answer (score 1):

See the bottom of the following page: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#_merge_strategies.

It describes how you can set different merge strategies with git attributes. In this case you always want the master version of your capistrano file to be in charge, not the one on your branch, e.g.

```
capistrano.file merge=ours
```

Ours refer to "our version of the file" relative to the branch you are on when doing the merge.